# Properties of the quadruple layer potential

Tags: potential-theory

What is known about the quadruple layer potential in 3D (on closed smooth surfaces)? In terms of jump relations, continuity on Hölder Spaces (and/or Sobolev spaces), and Calderon-type identities (regularization). I'm interested in the Laplace and also the Helmholtz case (the acoustic problem). Thanks

Comment: Is this the same as the hypersingular integral potential?

Comment: Timur, no- the kernel is of the form $\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial n_x^2}(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reference to a paper by Shidong Jiang  which may be useful as regards jump relations
: http://web.njit.edu/~jiang/Papers/jump.pdf